# Is there a way to clean up after adding transactions in ropsten network?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I'm playing around with an application using Ropsten test network for Ethereum blockchain. I am wondering if there is a way to delete things from there so they do not pollute the blockchain. Or is Ropsten is also immutable as the main one?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.

The whole point of a blockchain is its immutability. The Ropsten network primarily differs from the Ethereum mainnet in that Ropsten Ether is worthless (it's for testing only.) Rest is all same as any other Ethereum implementation. As a matter of fact, of all the testnets, the Ropsten network is the closest to the Ethereum mainnet.

EXTRA:

Interestingly, (or not so interestingly), even in your private ethereum chain, the best in terms of 'clearing up the mess' you can do is to remove last N blocks (which hold the transactions). As soon as you pick and remove things, you break the integrity and your chain will become corrupt and void.